# How we can Join Two Columns in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

We have 2 tables "JUNE" and "SEPTEMBER". there are 34 columns, like - id, date1, date2..... and up to date30 . same as for "SEPTEMBER" table. We have same id's in both the tables. but the values in the columns are different. We just want to join 3-4 columns in both the tables, and match the values, in not below one, the value should be greater than 1.

Comment: How about: SELECT J.DATE1, S.DATE1 FROM JUNE AS J, SEPTEMBER AS S WHERE ...

Comment: How about a more sensible database design...

Answer (score 1):

```
select j.DATE1, s.DATE1 
from JUNE j
left join SEPTEMBER s 
  on j.id=s.id
where value>1
```

Is that you looking for or please give us more information.

Comment: No bro, We do the same code , its showing error , May i know one thing. should we use, "SELECT JUNE.id, SEPTEMBER.id, JUNE.date1, JUNE.date2, SEPTEMBER.date1, SEPTEMBER.date2 FROM JUNE, SEPTEMBER WHERE value >1 "

Comment: it will display all the records on those 2 tables what was the error you having

Comment: Same Error occur, We are giving you the full informtn about, what we want, We have 12 table(names denoted by Month), all the tables having 32 columns, with many rows. what we want we are matching the availability in these dates, giving you a example :- If we travel in UK, jst booking a room, for three days(28June - 1July). we are checking the availability values from database tables in (June and July). each days are having different values. if any any of the dates value, having zero it means there is no Availability. each month table (stored the value from Date1 Date2 Date3 and so on Date30).

Comment: $num = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id,table_type,"disp",room_type,Date1 FROM JUNE Where table_type='disp' AND Date1!=0 ");

Comment: $num = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id,table_type,"disp",room_type,Date1 FROM JUNE Where table_type='disp' AND Date1!=0 ");  This Query helps me to get the single month data, but we are unable to get the data for 2 months. above script is working fine for me ...

Comment: join the other tables too... with your query

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT id, date1, date2, FROM JUNE WHERE value>1
UNION
SELECT id, date1, date2, FROM SEPTEMBER WHERE value>1
```

See also [MySQL docs on UNION syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html).